# polymer 3 starter kit: The requested URL /view1 was not found on this server. But just on internet

Tags: polymer

I init the polymer 3 starter-kit and everything works fine on local server with *polymer serve*
But if I upload the app to an online server and refreshing the page I get an error: *The requested URL /view1 was not found on this server.*
To be clear. Everything works fine if I use the menu. Then the url changes to domain/view1 and if I refresh the page at this point I get the error.

Comment: Where are you hosting your app? It would seem you might need to configure the routing for the hosting itself rather than the app itself

Comment: I am hosting at hetzner. Level 4 webhosting

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. I configured the .htaccess like this:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /`